# Question about closed subsets of affine schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $U = \operatorname{Spec} R[ \frac{X_0}{X_k}, \ldots, \frac{X_n}{X_k} ]$. Let $Z$ be a closed subset of $U$. I would like to know how I can show that 
$$
Z = \operatorname{Spec} R[ \frac{X_0}{X_k}, \ldots, \frac{X_n}{X_k} ]/J
$$
where 
$$
J = I(Z). 
$$
Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the Zariski topology on an affine scheme? What do the closed subsets look like?

Comment: I know that every closed subscheme of an affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec} S$ looks like $\operatorname{Spec} S/J$ for some ideal $J$. But not sure how to proceed from here...

Comment: What is your definition of $I(Z)$? It should be true that $I(Z) = \bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \in Z} \mathfrak{p}$ so if $Z = V(I)$, then $I(Z) = \sqrt I$, and $Z = V(I) = V(\sqrt I) = V(I(Z))$.